# Extracting Visual studio 2013 product key

Tags: windows

i have a virtual machine with server2012r2 installed which has Visual Studio 2013 installation with a product key i used many years ago.
I need to create new machine and install Visual studio 2013 there, id like to extract the key from the first machine and use the key on the new machine.
ive been reading some info about this which didnt get me too far, is there actual way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried [Nirsoft ProduKey](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html)? It seems to have support for Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you logged into Visual Studio on the machine? The license is bound to an MSDN account and/or an e-mail address.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, i cannot use 3rd party software, it is a product licsense so it is not connected to microsoft account

Comment: You can download the MSDN version here: http://beet.the-eye.eu/public/MSDN/Visual%20Studio%202013%20Update%205/, it should be activated by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the registry under key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\VERSION\Registration\SOMETHING`.

The key should be located inside the value named `PIDKEY` or `ProductID`.

Comment: Found it, Thanks for your much appriciated help!